# What role permission needed for the user to get the server_version in Amazon redshift DB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-redshift, dbmigrate

Currently i have a `user` called `master` in redshift which has SuperUser permission.

```
analytics=# \du
                      List of roles
  Role name  |          Attributes           | Member of 
-------------+-------------------------------+-----------
 master      | Superuser, Create DB          | 
 qac         |                               | 
 rdsdb       | Superuser, Create DB         +| 
             | Password valid until infinity | 
 report_user |                               |
```

But when i execute `show server_version;`, i'm getting an error.

```
analytics=# show server_version;
ERROR:  must be superuser to examine "server_version"
```

**Why i want show_version?**
I'm using `db-migrate` node_module in my node.js application. But when i try to run my migration scripts, i'm getting above error.
Here is my verbose of db-migrate:

```
sangeeth@sangeeth-kumar ~/Desktop/analytics-api $ ./node_modules/.bin/db-migrate up --config cfg/database.json --verbose
[INFO] Detected and using the projects local version of db-migrate. '/home/sangeeth/Desktop/analytics-api/node_modules/db-migrate/index.js'
[INFO] Using dev settings: { driver: 'pg',
  database: 'analytics',
  user: 'master',
  password: '******',
  host: '*****',
  port: '****' }
[INFO] require: db-migrate-pg
[INFO] connecting
[INFO] connected
[SQL] show server_version_num
[SQL] show server_version
[ERROR] error: must be superuser to examine "server_version"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/sangeeth/Desktop/analytics-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/sangeeth/Desktop/analytics-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/sangeeth/Desktop/analytics-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:607:20)
```

Note: I'm using postgres(pg) driver, since redshift is postgres compliance.

Anyone help me out?

Comment: Does `select version()` work?

Comment: Yes `select version();` works !

`analytics=# select version();
 PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.2915`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SHOW server_version;` is not supported. You would need to patch the library to use `SELECT version();` instead.

I will look into having this explicitly listed as being unsupported in this doc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here in case it helps someone in the future:

I found it was giving this issue as it was trying to create the initial `migrations` table. I patched the `db-migrate-pg/index.js` to replace the `show server_version` and `show server_version` with something arbitrary like `select 1`. I then created the migrations table myself in Redshift, and then I was able to run migrate:up, migrate:down, migrate:reset without any issues:

```
CREATE TABLE public.migrations (
    id integer,
    name character varying(255),
    run_on timestamp without time zone
);
```

USE WITH CAUTION, this has mostly been tested in a QA/dev environment